# urllib3 - Timeout and Retry

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

We would like to set the timeout for our REST call.  However, when the timeout is reached, will it automatically do a retry (up to the default max of 3)?  The documentation is not real clear.

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=os.getenv('SSL_CERT_FILE'))

try:

    resp = http.request(
        'GET',
        newurl,
        decode_content=True,
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json'},
        timeout=1
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, we ended up using this approach.

```
    retry = Retry(total=3, raise_on_status=True, backoff_factor=0.1, status_forcelist=[429,500,502,503,504])
timeout = Timeout(1.0)

http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=os.getenv('SSL_CERT_FILE'), retries=retry, timeout=timeout)

try:
    resp = http.request(
        'GET',
        newurl,
        decode_content=True,
        headers={'Accept':'application/json'}
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [urllib3 documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/) is very clear. You just need to pass the `retries` argument on the request method, it will automatically do a retry when the timeout is reached, here the [references: urllib3 Retrying Requests](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide.html#retrying-requests)

**So, the solution** is pass the `retries` argument on the request method,

```py
MAX_RETRIES=3
response = http.request('GET', url, retries=MAX_RETRIES)
```